# How to find the accessible ip to see the play framework homepage on aws ec2?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, playframework, amazon-ec2, cloud

I have connected the ec2 with my local environment. Then the play app is installed there along with all the dependencies. Now while I run it, it is showing,

```
--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
```

I can visit my public ip and there I can see the apache2 is running but while I visited public-ip:9000 it is showing nothing and page is not loaded.

Can anybody help me on, how to find the accessible ip to see the play framework homepage on aws ec2 ?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you have not allowed necessary incoming rules in the Security Group for your EC2 instance. Please make sure that you have allowed incoming rule for `port 9000` from `0.0.0.0/0 (anywhere)`.

If this is not the case, then provide more information like do you have any firewall (`iptables`) running on the instance? Do you actually have some process listening on port 9000 (`netstat -anp | grep 9000`) ?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html  Check the adding rules to security group in the documentation.

Comment: Hey slayedbylucifer Thanks for the reply. Yah I have not enabled the port 9000 , But in security group I have enabled default security group which allows every possible port right. If I need to enable 9000 port sheparately what will be the type | protocol | port range = 9000 ? | source = ?